# Give user a role DSharpPlus

Tags: c#, discord

I need a replacement for `IGuildUser` in the following code. (I am coding in DSharpPlus: https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus):

```
    [Command("i_accept"), Description("Accept the rules and gain full access to the server.")]
    [Hidden]
    public async Task accept(CommandContext ctx)
    {
        var user = ctx.User;
        var role = ctx.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Approved");
        await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);
        await ctx.RespondAsync("You are now approved!");
    }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit terse.  Can you explain the problem you are having in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 3):

You add roles to members inside a guild, this is done by first getting the `DiscordMember` instance and then adding the role.

```
var member = ctx.Member;
await ctx.Guild.GrantRoleAsync(member, role);
```

Note that this only works in guilds and will cause issues in DMs.